# session not keeping track in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

i am trying to display a set of movie list. i am suppose to maintain sessions and url parameters for user request of ratings(different type) and sorting order (by title and the rating). but one of the session is not been maintained.

controller:

```
def index

  @all_ratings = Movie.ratings
  @sorted_by = (params[:sort_by] || session[:sorted_by] || :none).to_sym
  @selected_ratings = params[:ratings] ? params[:ratings].keys : (session[:selected_ratings] || @all_ratings)

  session[:sorted_by] = @sorted_by
  session[:selected_ratings] = @selected_ratings
  @movies = Movie.where(:rating => @selected_ratings).order @sorted_by

end
```

each time i refresh a request the session[:selected_ratings] is maintained but the session[:sorted_by] is not. i worked out both of them in similar manner.but the order of movie list is never maintained. params[:sorted_by] work each time. please help.

view:

```
  %th {params[:sort_by] == "title" ? {:class => "hilite"} : {}}= link_to "Movie Title", movies_path(:sort_by => "title"), :id => "title_header"
  %th Rating
  %th{params[:sort_by] == "release_date" ? {:class => "hilite"} : {}}= link_to "Release Date", movies_path(:sort_by => "release_date"), :id => "release_date_header"
  %th More Info
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, in your view you should be referencing the `@sorted_by` instance var rather than `param[:sort_by]`, as the param might be nil.

Second, I suspect that `params[:sort_by]` is getting set to the empty string rather than `nil` as you expect. This is causing the or statement to short-circuit before it hits the session variable, and gives you an empty sort string every time.

Things to try: set up a  debugger ([pry](http://pryrepl.org/) and/or [the debugger gem](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debugger-gem)) and add a breakpoint in the index method somewhere. Then you can inspect the values of everything and see what's actually happening.